# divide a dataframe by another on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to divide a dataframe by another if the indexes math. I have 2 dataframes of them containing the country population from 2017 to 2020, the other, the quantity of the CO2 emitted by those countries. My only problem is, my second dataframe has more countries than the first and the order is  not exactly the same. Here is a glimpse of the situation.

```
df1                               df2
country  2017  2018 2019 2020    country  2017 2018 2019 2020
country1  120  140   200  440    country2 200   200  400  500
country2  100  200   120  250    country3 300   360  600  720
country5  25   25    50   35     country5 100   50   250  350
```

I tried *df1.div(df2)* but I only got NAN everywhere as a result. what I utimately want to do is divide df1 by df2 if country in df1 is also in df2. just like in my question i just have a result for country2.
Here is a sample result  :

```
df
country   2017   2018  2019   2020
country1  NAN    NAN   NAN    NAN
country2  2      1     3.3    2
Country5  4      2     5      10
```

Comment: Make sure the countries are spelled correctly and both dataframes have indecies set to country. In theory it should only give you NaN values for those countries that are missing in the first dataset.

Comment: post actual values with expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy I have updated the question.